# Avoiding "warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects" during git svn clone/fetch

Tags: git, git-svn

When running a `git svn clone` or `git svn fetch` against a large Subversion repository (100k+ commits), the fetch regularly stops with:

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.

gc --auto: command returned error: 255
```

In order to recover I have to follow the instructions, run a more aggressive prune and gc, remove the log-file and continue, only to have it happen again after another batch of say 10k commits are read.

How can this problem be avoided?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think if you set the config option `gc.pruneExpire` to `now`, at least temporarily during the import, it will avoid that message. With that option set, `git gc` will immediately delete *all* unreachable objects, instead of only ones that are at least two weeks old (the default). Coupled with a sensible value for `gc.auto` this should prevent them from accumulating to the point that you get that message.

Answer (score 14):

Self-answering.

`git svn` operations are amongst those which launch background `gc --auto` housekeeping operations.  In this case, I believe that the ongoing progress of the `git svn fetch` may result in the number of unreachable/loose objects at some point in the gc operation exceeding the auth-threshold, resulting in this warning.  Unfortunately it is fatal for the ongoing fetch.

My solution is to temporarily disable/suspect these gc operations, by deactivating gc auto as described in its manual page:

```
git config gc.auto 0
```

Once the `git svn fetch` operation completes, you can remove this config if desired, and run manual full gc, prune and repack operations to optimize the final repository.

Answer (score 9):

Started seeing this warning on git pull:

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 22, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 22 (delta 17), reused 22 (delta 17), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.

Already up-to-date.
```

Check out the warning file, not much there:

```
$ cat .git/gc.log
warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
```

Read the help:

```
$ git help gc
```

Sounds like we are supposed to be doing some of this on a regular basis

Run the occasionally recommended aggressive option

```
$ git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 41544, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40544/40544), done.
Writing objects: 100% (41544/41544), done.
Total 41544 (delta 30536), reused 7801 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking connectivity: 46959, done.
```

Remove the log warning:

```
$ rm .git/gc.log
```

Smile

```
:)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in this instance where removing `.git/gc.log` is the solution, said removal will be easier.

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), a pathname in an advice message has been made cut-and-paste ready.

See [commit b45c172](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b45c172e511dedb4032da833903fdd42ae50e496) (31 Aug 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 02d2632](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02d263277ab827a1a77cbb6f3c703e8b7181efde), 10 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`gc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b45c172e511dedb4032da833903fdd42ae50e496): remove trailing dot from "gc.log" line
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Jan Judas</sup>

> Remove the trailing dot from the warning we emit about `gc.log`.
> It's common for various terminal UX's to allow the user to select "words", and by including the trailing dot a user wanting to select the path to `gc.log` will need to manually remove the trailing dot.
>
> Such a user would also probably need to adjust the path if it e.g. had spaces in it, but this should address this very common case.